# ASP.NET MVC - Html.RenderPartial issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a usercontrol named "LoginUserControl.ascx" which I have placed in a master page.
Header of "LoginUserControl.ascx"

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MultiTechnologyWeb.Models.loginmodel>" %>
```

Then I used the below code to show the usercontrol in the masterpage.

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("LoginUserControl"); %>
```

On first run the page "index" is loaded. 
Notice the header of the "index" page, no model is specified. Thus page load successfully

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/MT.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
```

Now I click on the link to open register.aspx. I got the below error

*The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MultiTechnologyWeb.Models.registermodel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MultiTechnologyWeb.Models.loginmodel'.*

Header of "register.aspx" page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/MT.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MultiTechnologyWeb.Models.registermodel>" %>
```

So to my understanding model is being interchanged, so anybody can please help me on how to resolve this issue

**More Explanation**.............**LATEST**

I have debug, i know that the crash is occuring after the actionresult for register is finished execution.
Code below is for actionresult "register"

```
   public ActionResult register()
    {
        registermodel model;
        //some code here
    return View("register",model);
    }
```

So i'm just returning one type of model that is "registermodel", Would it be possible to return another model such as "loginmodel" by using a list or array to return multiple models in the same view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763631/multiple-model-in-a-single-view-mvc3

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<% Html.RenderAction("Logon","Account"); %>` in your MasterPage instead of using RenderPartial and in this action you just return the login partial you want to use in the header

```
public ActionResult Logon(){
// do your stuff
return PartialView("LoginUserControl");
}
```

By this way you could pass the `loginmodel` to the LogInPartial and pass `registermodel` to the register page

Comment: I have changed to code to  public ActionResult Logon()
        {
            loginmodel model =new loginmodel ();
            return PartialView("LoginUserControl", model);
        }

Comment: Did u use `Html.RenderAction(...)` instead of `RenderPartial()` ??

Answer (score 0):

Please not that RenderAction and RenderPartial are not the same.

RenderPartial will render only the view. While RenderAction will make a new MVC roundtrip, by making a new instance of the controller etc and returning the result.

To solve your issue you could pass in the `MultiTechnologyWeb.Models.loginmodel` where you call `<% Html.RenderPartial("LoginUserControl"); %>`. It would look like this:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("LoginUserControl", new MultiTechnologyWeb.Models.loginmodel()); %>
```

Or:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("LoginUserControl", Model.LoginModel); %>
```

Comment: I tried what you said but still doesn't work. I have just updated the issue description ....... check by line "More Explanation".............

Answer (score 0):

If you're not wanting to send a model to your partial view, which I've wanted to do in the past, you do have to at least pass something to the `RenderPartial` method.

This was the only method I could find that allowed me to now have to pass a model. I tried passing `null` and it continued to pass the parent model

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("LoginUserControl", new ViewDataDictionary()); %>
```