# ASP.NET MVC 4 Display data From 2 Model using EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model

I'm start learning ASP.NET MVC 4 and stuck displaying Data From 2 model in 1 File
Here's my Model

```
 public class mst_item
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayName("Item Code")]
    [Required]
    public string item_code{get;set;}

    [DisplayName("Item Name")]
    [Required]
    public string item_name{get;set;}        

    [DisplayName("Unit")]
    [Required]
    public mst_item_unit unit_id{ get; set; }

}


public class mst_item_unit
{
    [Key]
    public int unit_id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Unit")]
    public string unit_name { get; set; }


}
```

Then My Controller :

```
 public ActionResult Item()
 {
        var list_item = db.mst_item.Include("mst_item_unit").ToList();

        return View(list_item);
 }
```

Then How to display the unit_name based on the `mst_item.unit_id` in View using `INNER JOIN` or `Include`? something like :

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_name)
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.unit_name)
}
```

I get stuck here, But I success while displaying the `mst_item` data without joining `mst_item_unit` (just display the ID based on `mst_item.unit_id`) before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have a couple of issues:

1. The parameter to `Include` should be a navigation property on your entity, not the table name. In other words, change it to:

   ```
   var list_item = db.mst_item.Include("unit_id").ToList();
   ```
2. You have to access the properties of this second entity *through* the navigation property. In other words, this is the view code you would need:

   ```
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_name)
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.unit_id.unit_name)
   }
   ```

That said, you've also got some stylistic problems here, which since you're new, I'll point out.

1. Class and property names should be camel-cased, i.e. `MstItem`, rather than `mst_item`.
2. Navigation properties should be named after the objects they connect to, i.e. `unit_id` should be something like `MstItemUnit`, or just `Unit`, if you prefer. That removes the need to specify a display name for it, as well.
3. The use of the `_id` suffix on this navigation property is particularly troubling, because it implies that this property is an `int` or `Guid` - you know, something that could be used an id - whereas actually you're referencing a full-fledged object.
4. While not as important, it makes little sense to repeat the class name or a portion thereof in the property names of that class. For example, `unit_name` should just be `Name`. Obviously, it's the name of the unit, because that's the class.

With those in place, your code becomes much more readable and "human". For example:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Unit.Name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I'ts work when I changing my code style,
I try your first solution changing

var list_item = db.mst_item.Include("unit_id").ToList();   and
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.unit_id.unit_name)

But it's still shows error message : column unit_id_unit_id is not found
and no suggestion of unit_name while I typing item.unit_id.

So I tried to do your 2nd solution to change the code style
Then I overide the Entity name and the property name rather than Changing my Tables or Field name with camel case, and it's works!
and it's shows the item.Unit.name property suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You should be creating a ViewModel that will relate both your models, populate that ViewModel in your controller and use that in your View. The below link is very much your case.
[Multiple Models in a Single View (C# MVC3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763631/multiple-models-in-a-single-view-c-mvc3)